# How to make latexmk/lualatex work with spaces in filenames in Windows?

Tags: luatex, texlive, latexmk, texlive-2020

For example, try make identical tex files at `C:\a\b c\d.tex` and `C:\a\bc\d.tex`. Then try run `lualatex` with no arguments except the filenames. The first file will compile perfectly. The second one will fail miserably, as if `lualatex` was trying to read the filename as a .tex document:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
 restricted system commands enabled.
! I can't find file `c:'.
<to be read again>
\def
<*> "c:\a\b
         c\d.tex"
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ensure** all filenames use forward slashes instead of backslashes. If you're using `latexmk` automatically, there's a flag you can put in the command line arguments or in the RC file: `$MSWin_back_slash = 0;` which will do this automatically for you.

Comment: this killed 3 hours of my day... :((